# IOS App crash: EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL) Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0x8badf00d

Tags: ios, crash, crash-reports, ios-app-group

My app is getting crashed on TestFlight and on production while opening after some time again, please have a look at the `symbolicated` crash log below.

Please help me, I am struggling a lot because of the crash issue.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0x8badf00d
Termination Description: SPRINGBOARD, process-exit watchdog transgression: application<com.bankonus>:2014 exhausted real (wall clock) time allowance of 5.00 seconds | ProcessVisibility: Foreground | ProcessState: Running | WatchdogEvent: process-exit | WatchdogVisibility: Foreground | WatchdogCPUStatistics: ( | "Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 1.890 (user 1.890, system 0.000), 19% CPU", | "Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.001, 0% CPU" | )
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018a83a77c __ulock_wait + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018a6b10a8 _dlock_wait + 52
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018a6b0fe8 _dispatch_once_wait$VARIANT$mp + 112
3   bankonus                        0x000000010437a8e4 0x1041f8000 + 1583332
4   bankonus                        0x00000001043bc748 0x1041f8000 + 1853256
5   bankonus                        0x00000001043bc6a8 0x1041f8000 + 1853096
6   bankonus                        0x00000001043bab38 0x1041f8000 + 1846072
7   bankonus                        0x0000000104375958 0x1041f8000 + 1562968
8   bankonus                        0x0000000104375a54 0x1041f8000 + 1563220
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018a7099a8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018a70a524 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018a6bc5b4 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 904
12  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018a9c2748 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
13  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018a9bd61c __CFRunLoopRun + 1724
14  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018a9bcc34 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
15  GraphicsServices                0x0000000194b0638c GSEventRunModal + 160
16  UIKitCore                       0x000000018eaef22c UIApplicationMain + 1932
17  bankonus                        0x000000010420023c 0x1041f8000 + 33340
18  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018a844800 start + 4
```

Thanks

Comment: That's only giving system symbols.  Properly symbolicated it should also show routine names from "bankonus" instead of address offsets.  Whatever your code is doing, it seems to be blocking the main thread for too long.

Comment: So, how can I get the detailed symbolicated report?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2151/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008184-CH1-SYMBOLICATION